# How to use ETags in YouTube API

Tags: node.js, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-channels

Apparently we can use ETags to see if the channel/playlist has been updated or not based on the following statement from [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#etags):

> when your application requests a stored resource again, it specifies
>   the ETag associated with that resource. If the resource has changed,
>   the API returns the modified resource and the ETag associated with
>   that version of the resource. If the resource has not changed, the API
>   returns an HTTP 304 response (Not Modified), which indicates that the
>   resource has not changed.

But I tried to get get a channel data which is not changing but after refreshing a couple of times it seems ETag jumps to different values!

Comment: Show us your code you're testing this with.

Comment: @idbehold I just call the endpoint directly in my browser!

Comment: And that endpoint is?

Comment: It is this endpoint but with the right key instead of XXX  https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCYMWnCecPvpQJj8sBPUi4bA&key=XXXXXX&maxResults=50&regionCode=us&videoEmbeddable=true&type=video&order=date

Comment: It seems like you'll get 304 responses if you remove the `&order=date` from the end of the query string.

Comment: Are you sure nothing has changed?  Maybe you got a new subscriber or something.

Comment: @JAL The funny thing is randomly jumps between two numbers

Comment: @idbehold But do you see etag jumps between two different numbers randomly?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just hit the endpoint again and compare etag values; rather, you have to make the request, store the etag value, then pass that etag value in with subsequent requests. You'll do this is the request header ... set the HTTP header "If-None-Match" to the value of your etag. If nothing has changed, you'll get back a 304 (instead of any content or metadata). If something has changed, you'll get a new result, and you take that new etag and store it instead of the old one.

The Google API Client for Javascript supports this header; when you create your gapi.client.request object, you'll pass in an object for arguments; one of the parameters of this object is 'headers,' in which you can set 'If-None-Match' to be equal to the etag you want to check.

(Note, also, that there's an 'If-Match' header, which can also work with etags, where it will only return the content if the resource is the SAME as the one you'd requested previously ... probably not as many use cases for that, but it exists and is supported.)

Comment: Thanks so much for clarification! But I believe the etag shouldn't flip between two numbers randomly! Dont you think this is a bug from YouTube API? "If-None-Match" is doing exactly what I do but in a more efficient way which does not show the result if the result has not been changed, but still it is using etag which randomly flips between two numbers irrespective of whether data has been changed or not...

Comment: The etag just represents the state of a request; there's nothing that says multiple etags can't represent the same state. But if a given state changes, then any etags that represented that state will be invalidated. (As to why they might use multiple etags for the same state, I can only conjecture ... it could be a performance thing, for example, having to do with different caching servers. Or something else entirely.)